# php if else condition in variable as string

Tags: php, if-statement

I have if else condition as string like `$cond = '40 < 50 and 60 > 70';` how can I execute it in PHP with out exec.
`if ($cond)` not working as it just pass if variable exists or not.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). But keep in mind that it has its security riscs (see the linked documentation page).

Comment: Can't we use without eval ?